# Javascript Key Handler

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, keyevent

I have a Javascript key handler function and I'm trying to use it in a game that I'm working out but it doesn't seem to be quite working and I'm not sure if its the editor or the code has errors.  My code is as shown:

```
var myKey = {
    pressedKeys: [],
    LEFT: 37,
    UP: 38,
    RIGHT: 39,
    DOWN: 40,
    isPressed: function(zKey){
        return this.pressedKeys[zKey];
    },
    onkeyDown: function(event){
        this.pressedKeys[event.keyCode] = true;
    },
    onkeyUp: function(event){
        this.pressedKeys[event.keyCode] = false;   
    },
};

window.addEventListener("keydown", myKey.onkeyDown);
window.addEventListener("keyup", myKey.onkeyUp);

var checkInput = function(){
    if(myKey.pressedKeys[myKey.LEFT]){
        confirm("Pressed Left");
    }
}

var gameLoop = function(){
    checkInput();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

The game loop animation frame is called the first time in a main function that's not shown here.  I don't understand what could be going wrong.  I tried hard coding numbers and still nothing but it could very well be my editor.

Comment: Probably should change `confirm` to `console.log` to prevent interference with onkeyUp

Answer (score 2):

When you get a reference to a method and use that as an event handler, the function is no longer associated with the object. `this` inside the function is not a reference to the `myKey` object, but a reference to the `window` object (as that is the object where the event happens).

You can use the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to specify the context for the functions:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", myKey.onkeyDown.bind(myKey));
window.addEventListener("keyup", myKey.onkeyUp.bind(myKey));
```

Note that the `bind` method is not supported in some older browsers, for example IE8 and older, so you would need a 'polyfill' if you need to support them. There is one in the documentation that I linked to above.

You can also use a function wrapper to call the methods:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){ myKey.onkeyDown(e); });
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){ myKey.onkeyUp(e); });
```

Comment: Your first paragraph kind of implies that `this` will be the global object within *any* event handlers, but that's only the case in this instance because the event is explicitly attached to `window` - if it were attached to some other element then `this` should refer to that element.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes, you are right, thansk for spotting that. I corrected the text.

Comment: Thank you this helped me quite a bit.  i got the keydown event listener to call but the keyup event listener never fires off so i need to figure that out but otherwise thank you much very helpful =)